# How to retrieve images from database using jquery and servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, servlets

I need to retrieve the images which is stored in my oracle 11g R2 database. I'm trying to retrive the images using Jquery and servlet, And placing into the css division. But I'm a newbie in this. I know using json objects we can do this stuff. Please anyone tell me how to do

Comment: U wont get here 'how to do' unless you show us 'what have you tried' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a request that returns a list of the names of all images (so that you know what to retrieve)
2. Make a servlet that serves images - gets the name as GET parameter, looks it up in the database (e.g. via JDBC) and streams the result back into the `response.getOutputStream()`, and set the correct content type